# Accessing unkeyed element in JSON via Ruby json gem

Tags: ruby, json

I'm working with the Ruby json gem.

I have a JSON response that looks like this:

```
json =
  {
    "BTC_LTC": {
      "last": "0.0172",
      "lowestAsk": "0.0174",
      "highestBid": "0.0172",
      "percentChange": "-0.01189063",
      "baseVolume": "6.42658984",
      "quoteVolume": "369.67833179",
      "isFrozen": "0"
    },
    "BTC_NXT": {
      "last": "0.00011999",
      "lowestAsk": "0.00012998",
      "highestBid": "0.00010703",
      "percentChange": "0.1999",
      "baseVolume": "40.46829556",
      "quoteVolume": "354723.19760885",
      "isFrozen": "0"
    }
  }
```

Assuming I slurp up the JSON like so:

```
obj = JSON.parse(json)
```

how do I access the first element so that I have an output like

```
 "BTC_LTC"
"BTC_NXT"
```

I've tried:

```
obj.each do |elem|
  puts element
end

obj.each do |elem|
  puts obj[elem]
end
```

In short, how do I access "val" in {"val": {"key":"value"}}?

Comment: From next time please use [this site](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/gfx/demos/beautify.html) to *beautify* your JSON and post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a key-value pair system and you want the keys:

```
obj.keys # => ["BTC_LTC", "BTC_NXT"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy

```
json = '{
    "BTC_LTC": {
        "last": "0.0172",
        "lowestAsk": "0.0174",
        "highestBid": "0.0172",
        "percentChange": "-0.01189063",
        "baseVolume": "6.42658984",
        "quoteVolume": "369.67833179",
        "isFrozen": "0"
    },
    "BTC_NXT": {
        "last": "0.00011999",
        "lowestAsk": "0.00012998",
        "highestBid": "0.00010703",
        "percentChange": "0.1999",
        "baseVolume": "40.46829556",
        "quoteVolume": "354723.19760885",
        "isFrozen": "0"
    }
}'

require 'json'

obj = JSON.parse(json)
obj.each { |k, _| puts k }
# >> BTC_LTC
# >> BTC_NXT
```

Answer (score 0):

For key-value collections, `each` gives you the key *and* the value:

```
obj.each do |key, value|
    puts key
end
```